# GitKraken: Configured SSH key is invalid for self-hoster git repository

Tags: git, ssh, gitkraken

I'm trying use GitKraken with my existing git repository hosted on a Synology NAS (web-managed, if this can make a difference).

I could clone and push elements via command prompt, no problem with

```
git clone ssh://user@myServervolume1/path/myGit
```

I can clone/commit/pull via command prompt but when I do it via GitKraken, I get a "Configured SSH key is invalid" error.

So I tried by generating a new key via GitKraken and installing it as described [here](https://gist.github.com/walkerjeffd/374750c366605cd5123d), but nothing changed. Event [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41145054/invalid-ssh-keys-on-gitkraken/46460522) was no help - what am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT**

YES I ***CAN*** `git clone, push, pull` with users from command line, and I can also `ssh` to the server, although only with admin users (seems to be Synology's new standard). So I made absolutely sure that I use the admin user in the remote URL - same problem.

Here is the output for `ssh -vvv`:

```
    OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
    debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
    debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
    debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
    debug2: resolving "my.server.com" port 22
    debug2: ssh_connect_direct
    debug1: Connecting to my.server.com [I.HIDE.THE.IP] port 22.
    debug1: Connection established.
    debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
    debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
    debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
    debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
    debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
    debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
    debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
    debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
    debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
    debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
    debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
    debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
    debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
    debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
    debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
    debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4
    debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4 pat OpenSSH_7.0*,OpenSSH_7.1*,OpenSSH_7.2*,OpenSSH_7.3*,OpenSSH_7.4*,OpenSSH_7.5*,OpenSSH_7.6*,OpenSSH_7.7* compat 0x04000002
    debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
    debug1: Authenticating to my.server.com:22 as 'admin_user'
    debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/user/.ssh/known_hosts"
    debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:1
    debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from my.server.com
    debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
    debug3: send packet: type 20
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
    debug3: receive packet: type 20
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
    debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
    debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,ext-info-c
    debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
    debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
    debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
    debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
    debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
    debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
    debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
    debug2: languages ctos: 
    debug2: languages stoc: 
    debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
    debug2: reserved 0 
    debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
    debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
    debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
    debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
    debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
    debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
    debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
    debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
    debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
    debug2: languages ctos: 
    debug2: languages stoc: 
    debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
    debug2: reserved 0 
    debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
    debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
    debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
    debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
    debug3: send packet: type 30
    debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
    debug3: receive packet: type 31
    debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:xrbGE5Me8Wy3z4vLPtZmq88w7uX0MnKUT/SxLiTxwR4
    debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/user/.ssh/known_hosts"
    debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:1
    debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from my.server.com
    debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/user/.ssh/known_hosts"
    debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:2
    debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from I.HIDE.THE.IP
    debug1: Host 'my.server.com' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
    debug1: Found key in /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:1
    debug3: send packet: type 21
    debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
    debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
    debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
    debug3: receive packet: type 21
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
    debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
    debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
    debug1: Will attempt key:  RSA SHA256:mxkdZTWy2TZ48/Sww9rjP7GWwLPhyH43RGZouRgodtM agent
    debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa 
    debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa 
    debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
    debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk 
    debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519 
    debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk 
    debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_xmss 
    debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
    debug3: send packet: type 5
    debug3: receive packet: type 7
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
    debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
    debug3: receive packet: type 6
    debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
    debug3: send packet: type 50
    debug3: receive packet: type 51
    debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
    debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
    debug3: preferred gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
    debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
    debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
    debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
    debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
    debug1: Offering public key:  RSA SHA256:mxkdZTWy2TZ48/Sww9rjP7GWwLPhyH43RGZouRgodtM agent
    debug3: send packet: type 50
    debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
    debug3: receive packet: type 51
    debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
    debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa
    debug3: no such identity: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory
    debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa
    debug3: no such identity: /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
    debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa
    debug3: no such identity: /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
    debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
    debug3: no such identity: /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk: No such file or directory
    debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519
    debug3: no such identity: /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
    debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
    debug3: no such identity: /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk: No such file or directory
    debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_xmss
    debug3: no such identity: /home/user/.ssh/id_xmss: No such file or directory
    debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
    debug3: authmethod_lookup password
    debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
    debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
    debug1: Next authentication method: password
    admin_user@my.server.com's password: 
    debug3: send packet: type 50
    debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
    debug3: receive packet: type 52
    debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
    Authenticated to my.server.com ([I.HIDE.THE.IP]:22).
    debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
    debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
    debug2: channel 0: send open
    debug3: send packet: type 90
    debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
    debug3: send packet: type 80
    debug1: Entering interactive session.
    debug1: pledge: network
    debug3: receive packet: type 80
    debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
    debug3: receive packet: type 91
    debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback start
    debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
    debug3: ssh_packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x10
    debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
    debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
    debug3: send packet: type 98
    debug1: Sending environment.
    debug3: Ignored env SHELL
    debug3: Ignored env SESSION_MANAGER
    debug3: Ignored env QT_ACCESSIBILITY
    debug3: Ignored env COLORTERM
    debug3: Ignored env XDG_CONFIG_DIRS
    debug3: Ignored env XDG_MENU_PREFIX
    debug3: Ignored env GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID
    debug1: Sending env LC_ADDRESS = de_CH.UTF-8
    debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
    debug3: send packet: type 98
    debug3: Ignored env GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE
    debug1: Sending env LC_NAME = de_CH.UTF-8
    debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
    debug3: send packet: type 98
    debug3: Ignored env SSH_AUTH_SOCK
    debug3: Ignored env XMODIFIERS
    debug3: Ignored env DESKTOP_SESSION
    debug1: Sending env LC_MONETARY = de_CH.UTF-8
    debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
    debug3: send packet: type 98
    debug3: Ignored env SSH_AGENT_PID
    debug3: Ignored env GTK_MODULES
    debug3: Ignored env PWD
    debug3: Ignored env LOGNAME
    debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP
    debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_TYPE
    debug3: Ignored env GPG_AGENT_INFO
    debug3: Ignored env XAUTHORITY
    debug3: Ignored env GJS_DEBUG_TOPICS
    debug3: Ignored env WINDOWPATH
    debug3: Ignored env HOME
    debug3: Ignored env USERNAME
    debug3: Ignored env IM_CONFIG_PHASE
    debug1: Sending env LC_PAPER = de_CH.UTF-8
    debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
    debug3: send packet: type 98
    debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
    debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
    debug3: send packet: type 98
    debug3: Ignored env LS_COLORS
    debug3: Ignored env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP
    debug3: Ignored env VTE_VERSION
    debug3: Ignored env GNOME_TERMINAL_SCREEN
    debug3: Ignored env INVOCATION_ID
    debug3: Ignored env MANAGERPID
    debug3: Ignored env GJS_DEBUG_OUTPUT
    debug3: Ignored env LESSCLOSE
    debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_CLASS
    debug3: Ignored env TERM
    debug1: Sending env LC_IDENTIFICATION = de_CH.UTF-8
    debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
    debug3: send packet: type 98
    debug3: Ignored env LESSOPEN
    debug3: Ignored env USER
    debug3: Ignored env GNOME_TERMINAL_SERVICE
    debug3: Ignored env DISPLAY
    debug3: Ignored env SHLVL
    debug1: Sending env LC_TELEPHONE = de_CH.UTF-8
    debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
    debug3: send packet: type 98
    debug3: Ignored env QT_IM_MODULE
    debug1: Sending env LC_MEASUREMENT = de_CH.UTF-8
    debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
    debug3: send packet: type 98
    debug3: Ignored env XDG_RUNTIME_DIR
    debug1: Sending env LC_TIME = de_CH.UTF-8
    debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
    debug3: send packet: type 98
    debug3: Ignored env JOURNAL_STREAM
    debug3: Ignored env XDG_DATA_DIRS
    debug3: Ignored env PATH
    debug3: Ignored env GDMSESSION
    debug3: Ignored env DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
    debug1: Sending env LC_NUMERIC = de_CH.UTF-8
    debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
    debug3: send packet: type 98
    debug3: Ignored env _
    debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
    debug3: send packet: type 98
    debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback done
    debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
    debug3: receive packet: type 99
    debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
    debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 0
    debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
    debug3: receive packet: type 99
    debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
    debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
```

Comment: Either `git clone user@myServer:volume1/path/myGit` or `git clone ssh://user@myServer/volume1/path/myGit`

Comment: ok, that fixes the malformed url problem when using the `ssh://` - but I still cannot get rid of the SSH key issue... Can I not use the password each time?

Comment: Test ssh with `ssh -vvv user@myServer` — what is the text output? If you login and there are no errors — test Git: can you clone/fetch/pull/push from the command line, without GitKraken? This is to find out where the problem is — is it with ssh, Git or GitKraken. PS. You'd better not ask 2 different questions at once, even related.

Comment: ok turns out I had to add my user to admins and do all the steps to install SSL certif on remote with the actual user... Now it works!