# Gitkraken not working as says loaded tried loading github and SSH seems to be not working

Tags: git, github, ssl, gitkraken

OS: Windows 10 Home 21H2
Software: Gitkraken, Github
Gitkraken version: Gitkraken Version x68 8.6.0

Hello, I've got a student account for github and setting up gitkraken with it the thing is I have fully set up git and gitkraken with the SSH yet the application says loading and whenever I click add to github button it says no ssh seetting detected.

I have tried doing this: [Invalid SSH keys on GitKraken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41145054/invalid-ssh-keys-on-gitkraken)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why doesn't my SSH key work for connecting to github?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9960897/why-doesnt-my-ssh-key-work-for-connecting-to-github)

Answer (score 0):

Despite "not working" is not an error description, this sounds alike: [I'm having an SSH issue](https://support.gitkraken.com/integrations/authentication/#im-having-an-ssh-issue)
Likely there's no `pageant` or the keys might not have the expected `authorized_keys` format.
HTTPS repositories are commonly easier to setup than SSH repositories on Windows.